# Does this set of operators cause undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer

As far as I understand, things like `++i++` are not allowed in C/C++ because they break a rule that variables cannot be written to multiple times in a single statement. The result is undefined behaviour.

Could someone confirm if this also applies to my statement: `++i %= j`?

I would like a for loop where I increment `i` around a circular buffer (size `j`) starting at an arbitrary point `p` until I get back to point `p`.

```
for(int i = p+1 ; i != p; ++i %= j  )
{
    if (buffer[i].ready()) 
    {
        buffer[i].do_something();
        p = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

I could do it in more lines of code, but would rather not.

Comment: It is well-defined.

Comment: `++i %= j` doesn't appear in the code snippet.

Comment: Fixed. You're right.

Comment: Why not `i = (i + 1) % j` and avoid *smart* code?

Comment: If you have to ask if it's well-defined, it's *bad* code.

Comment: Just for the record (since everyone answered about C++ and the question includes C). In C `++i %= j` will not even compile because `++i` is not an lvalue. Both gcc and clang correctly reject it.

Comment: I'd like to second what @Art said.  You are touching on a point where C and C++ subtly differ.  C says ++i is an rvalue while C++ says ++i is a lvalue referencing i.  Another example where C and C++ disagree similarly is on assignment operators.  In C++, the expression x = y (typically) yields an lvalue reference to x, whereas in C the expression yields an rvalue.  Writing code on basic types like ints that differs in C and C++ is begging for trouble.  In this case, the compiler will likely save you with syntax errors for C, but there are probably other examples that would pass.  Not good!

Comment: Another valid variant: `for (int i = p+1 ; i != p; ++i, i %= j  )`

Comment: I also wanted to point out that you likely have a subtle bug in your code when `p == j - 1` because you add one but don't mod when you initialize `i`.  You also don't process `p` itself.  Is that what you want?

Comment: If in doubt better avoid it, especially when safe variant is short and readable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you say `++i % j`, which means 'Increment i (and store the new value in i), then calculate the modulo of i and j. But that value is not stored anywhere.

To get a wrap around loop, you can use `i = (i+1)%j`

Comment: Yes, that's very clear and simple.  I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm new to StackOverflow. How should I edit the answer so it fit's with the slightly changed question?

Comment: @HeavensInc your answer perfectly matches the question, no need tot edit.

Comment: There is a limit in SO regarding how soon you're allowed to accept an answer, I just had to wait for that timer to expire.

Answer (score 2):

## **The behaviour is undefined pre C++17.**

`++i %= j` is equivalent to `i = ++i % j`.

This is a dressed up version of `i = ++i`, and *everyone* knows that is UB.

Comment: Please downvote the living daylights out of this if I'm wrong! Unless I need more coffee I can't see any other way of rationalising this.

Comment: According to Nathan Oliver, only the sequencing of the operands relative to each-other is unspecified prior to C++17. They are still both evaluated before the compound assignment. All well defined. (No need to downvote however, it still looks weird)

Comment: Of course. But it isn't a dressed-up version of it.

Comment: So you're saying that "++i %= j is equivalent to i = ++i % j" is incorrect? I'm being a bit naughty here - punting an answer and watching out for downvotes to prove its falsehood or otherwise.

Comment: Yes. Because the standard clearly specifies the compound assignment is done as a single evaluation, not as two (end of the first quote in my answer, not in bold).

Comment: That only applies from C++17 owards no?

Comment: I don't know, I only have the C++1z draft handy. Not impossible that like the relative order of lhs and rhs, this too is different in C++14.

Comment: @StoryTeller From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4176333/4342498) if `++i = 2;` is UB then `++i <any compound assignment> 2;` is also UB

Comment: @Bathsheba Yes, it's not equivalent. In the former, the calculation of `%=` is sequenced after calculation of both `++i` and `j`. Yes, the relative order of `++i` and `j` is undefined, but we don't care. For the latter, we have operator `=` and two operands: `i` and `++i % j`, and calculation of `i` may or may not intersect with calculation of `++i % j`, causing a UB.

Comment: @Bathsheba So, is `i = ++i;` defined behavior in C++17?  For both scalars and classes?  Is `i = i++;` still UB for scalars, even in C++17?  What about for classes?  I'm still living in ANSI C world over here ...

Comment: @Bathsheba [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points/4183735#4183735) says that `i = ++i;` is defined behavior since C++11, even for scalars.

Comment: Hum. There's lots of complexity here. On the grounds that I've hit the rep count and deleting this question today would not impact my score, I think I should wiki this so a good answer could emerge. What do you all think?

Comment: @Bathsheba I agree that there's lots of complexity here between the various versions of C++ on these kinds of questions.  I'm too clueless about SE to advise you well about your specific question.

Comment: And in C++17, even `++i = ++i;` and more complicated variants are now well defined.  Ick.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your code is well defined (in C++17 anyway). Quoting the standard:

[[expr.ass]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#1)

> The assignment operator (=) and the **compound assignment operators all
>   group right-to-left**. All require a modifiable lvalue as their left
>   operand and return an lvalue referring to the left operand. The result
>   in all cases is a bit-field if the left operand is a bit-field. **In all
>   cases, the assignment is sequenced after the value computation of the
>   right and left operands**, and before the value computation of the
>   assignment expression. **The right operand is sequenced before the left
>   operand.** With respect to an indeterminately-sequenced function call,
>   the operation of a compound assignment is a single evaluation.

[[expr.pre.incr]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.pre.incr#1)

> The operand of prefix ++ is modified by adding 1. The operand shall be
>   a modifiable lvalue. The type of the operand shall be an arithmetic
>   type other than cv bool, or a pointer to a completely-defined object
>   type. **The result is the updated operand; it is an lvalue,** and it is a
>   bit-field if the operand is a bit-field. The expression ++x is
>   equivalent to x+=1.

The text in bold means your code pretty much has the following semantics:

```
auto& __j = j;   // refer to j
auto& __i = ++i; // refer to i after the increment
__i %= __j;
```

If the expression looks fishy to you despite the standards reassurance, you can always sequence it yourself with the comma operator.

```
for(... ; ... ; (++i, i %= j))
```

Comment: Looks like you're quoting C++17.  C++14 does not have *The right operand is sequenced before the left operand*

Comment: @NathanOliver - Good to know. Does the rest still apply?

Comment: I believe so, also your links and quotes are swapped around.

Comment: @StoryTeller Oh, joy!  Does that mean `++i = ++i;` is now defined behavior in C++17???

Comment: Even more interestingly (to me at least), when i is a class, `++i = ++i;` is no longer equivalent to `i.operator=(++i, ++i);`

Comment: @jschultz410 - No need for phrasing your comment in such a manner. Yes `++i = ++i` is sequenced in a well defined manner in c++17(for primitives). That is fact, and stating it doesn't make me an advocate for writing such code. Operator overloading is not covered by these paragraphs, but by a different section entirely.

Comment: @StoryTeller It was not my intention to imply that you support writing that kind of code.  I was making fun of the ridiculous kinds of statements that the ever expanding sequencing of operations the C++ standard is allowing.  Why don't they just go all the way, as some other languages have, and fully define things like `x = (++i + ++x) * (++i - ++x);`???  It certainly can be done, and wouldn't break any old code.

Answer (score 2):

The code `++i %= j` is identical to the following code:

```
operator %= (++i, j);
```

In the standard (§1.9/15) it's stated that

> The value computations of the operands of an operator are sequenced before the value computation of the result of the operator.

While "value computations" includes:

- value computations (including determining the identity of an object for glvalue evaluation and fetching a value previously assigned to an object for prvalue evaluation) and
- initiation of side effects.

So, here the compiler is forced to first calculate `++i` and `j` (in any order), including the side-effect of `++`, and call `operator %=` only after these calculations finished. So, it's a **well-defined behavior** since at least C++11.

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points/4183735#4183735) for more details.

Comment: From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4176333/4342498) if `++i = 2;` is UB then `++i <any compound assignment> 2;` is also UB

Comment: @NathanOliver, please explain. I totally agree that `++i %= j` is **well-defined**. Moreover, I reference exactly the same answer as you do.

Comment: There is no sequence point between the `++i` and the `%= j`.  Since those are unsequenced the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @NathanOliver Agree that there's no sequence point because we don't have any sequence points in modern c++. But since `The value computations of the operands of an operator are sequenced before the value computation of the result of the operator`, calculations of both `++i` and `j` are sequenced before calculation of `operator %=`, as its operands. Yes, relative order of `++i` and `j` is undefined (and they may even overlap), but who cares? If I have a mistake in my reasoning, please point exactly on it.

Comment: What is going to happen first, the `++i` or the `%=`?  We don't know, they are handled in a unspecified sequence.  Because of that the result is undefined.

Comment: @NathanOliver, Isn't `++i` an operand of `%=`? If yes, then calculation of `++i` should be sequenced before calculation of `%=`, and the sequence is not unspecified.

Comment: It may or may not be.  We don't know.  Lets say `i` is 2 and `j` is 5.  When you have `++i %= j` the compiler can chose to do `3 %= 5` (applying the `++` first) or `++(2 %= 5)`.  Since both are valid and both produce different results it is UB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147364/discussion-between-alexeykuzmin0-and-nathanoliver).

Comment: @NathanOliver - The grammar rules only allow the first of those options to be viable. The grammar for [assignment expressions](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass#1) lists the first operand as a logical-or-expression. If you follow the grammar (and links) long enough, you will see that a unary-expression (like ++) is a logical-or-expression. It must be `(++i) %= j`.

Comment: I don't see how `++++i` can be well-defined but `++i = 2` not be, the first is `auto& __i = ++i; ++__i;` and the second is `auto& __i = ++i; __i = 2;` as per the requirements of sequencing before. Similar arguments hold for compound assignments, unless I'm sorely mistaken.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 I'm not sure exactly what to think anymore.  I'm not sure which one is right.

Comment: @PasserBy I think it has to do with (at least pre C++11) that the ++ and = can happen in either order.

Comment: @NathanOliver It's stated (albeit not very obviously) that this pertains to post-c++11, I'm pretty sure it's UB before that

Comment: Based on the answer everyone is pointing at, it seems `++i %= j;` was UB before C++11, but has been well defined starting in C++11 forwards.  Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already answered that your code is valid C++11 and later, but is undefined behavior for earlier versions of C++ and won't even compile in C (ignoring class member fcn calls, of course).  All of which says you should probably use a more explicit form to achieve your desired end.

I also wanted to point out that you likely have a subtle bug in your code when `p == j - 1` because you add one but don't mod when you initialize `i`, making you access beyond the end of the array in that case.

You also never process the element at index `p`.  Is that **really** what you want?  If you repeatedly executed this code and none of the other buffers were `ready()`, then you would keep skipping over checking if `buffer[p].ready()`.

More correct, more universal code (that still doesn't check the element at index `p`):

```
int i;

for (i = (p + 1) % j; i != p && !buffer[i].ready(); ++i, i %= j);

if (i != p)
{
  buffer[i].do_something();
  p = i;
}
```

A version that starts by processing the element at index `p`, but stops after going over the array at most once:

```
int i = p;

while (!buffer[i].ready() && (++i, i %= j, i != p));

if (buffer[i].ready())
{
  buffer[i].do_something();
  p = i;
}
```

There is a subtle point about the above version.  If `!buffer[p].ready()` when we first enter the loop, we go through the whole array, and none the other elements are `ready()` either, then we will exit the loop with `i == p`.  We will then interrogate `buffer[p]` again asking if it is `ready()`.  So, it is possible to ask `buffer[p].ready()` twice, which may or may not be important (e.g. - if it has side effects).  Heads up!

Here's a version that avoids that issue, but checks `buffer[p].ready()` last:

```
int i = p;

while ((++i, i %= j, i != p) && !buffer[i].ready());

if (i != p || buffer[p].ready())
{
  buffer[i].do_something();
  p = i;
}
```